# Can we use the express4 with underscore.js?

Tags: node.js, express, underscore.js, ejs, embedded-javascript

Can we use the express4 with underscore.js?

I want to print the variable "name" in index.ejs

Is it possible?

In underscore.js capabilities Express4 Is there another method to use with node.js?

PS: underscore.js, express4 ( engine ejs )

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1><%= title %></h1>

    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  <h1><%= name %></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var _ = require("underscore");

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

   _.template("hello: <%= name %>");  

  res.render('index', { title:'hi'});

});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);





// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You don't need the `_.template` call inside index.js, it's commonly used for client-side template rendering, so as you're using EJS as your template engine, it's useless in your case. You just need to pass the `name` inside the JSON object in `res.render`, note that you're already passing the `title` attribute properly.

So your last line inside the get method would be like
    `res.render('index', { 
        title: 'hi',
        name: 'my name here'
    });`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know. But I was looking for an example I can use Express4 together with the underscorejs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For node js you should use the underscore's wrapper package - [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/)

Install:

```
npm i --save lodash
```

Usage:

```
var _ = require('lodash/dist/lodash.underscore');

_.map([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n * 3; });
// → [3, 6, 9]
```